# Typescript Object is possibly null even inside an if statement checking that the object is not null

Tags: javascript, typescript

I'm trying to access a property inside of an object inside of an array based on a provided index, and even though I check for that object not to be null, typescript still complains that it could be null.

Also "selectedIndex" is actually a react state in my project.

```
const arrayOfObjects: {bar:{baz: string; qux: string;}}[] = [{bar: {baz: 'value', qux: 'value'}}];

let selectedIndex: number = 0; //can be changed

if (arrayOfObjects[selectedIndex].bar !== null) {
  doSomethingWith(arrayOfObjects[selectedIndex].bar.baz);
  // here there will be a typescript error saying that "bar" Object is possibly null
}
```

Any idea?

Comment: I can't reproduce the issue. What version of TS are you using? Can it be an IDE cache problem?

Comment: Maybe if (arrayOfObjects[selectedIndex] && arrayOfObjects[selectedIndex].bar !== null)

Comment: I'm using typescript ~3.7.2 with react-scripts 4.0.3, I'll try to update it. Thanks!

Comment: upgraded to typescript 4.3.0, still same issue

Comment: The problem was I was saving the index into a react state, and apparently that can change between evaluating the item in the if statement, and what the statement returns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is due to the selectedIndex being a react state value which can change between statements

```
let var = arrayOfObjects[selectedIndex].bar;   
if (var) { 
  doSomething(var.baz) 
}
```

Comment: It seems to be tsc its self, I don't have a "clean" command in my package.json, any idea if yarn has an equivalent? Also, not sure if this matters, but in my code "selectedIndex" is actually a state in a react functional component, created with the useState hook.

Comment: Ahh... is it possible for the state value to change between the if and the next thing due to react magic? Try `let var = arrayOfObjects[selectedIndex].bar;    if (var) { doSomething(var.baz) }`

Comment: That is exactly what the problem was, no idea React could do that, I used your suggested fix and it worked! Please edit that into your answer so I can pick it as the accepted one.